# Javascript stopped working in Rails Rspec Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have the following setup in my system.rb helper file:

```
require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"

RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test 
  end
  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do 
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end 
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  [
    "headless",
    "window-size=1280x1280",
    "--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess",
    "disable-gpu" 
  ].each { |arg| options.add_argument(arg) }

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options, clear_local_storage: true, clear_session_storage: true)

end

Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
  "screenshot"
end

Capybara::Screenshot.webkit_options = { width: 1586, height: 768 }

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 4


Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js")
end
```

I am using Rails 5.2, selenium-webdriver 3.141.0, capybara 2.18, chromedriver-helper 2.1.0.

Here is a typical test:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Queues the Error Accounting Job ", type: :system,  js: true do
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  let!(:job)  { create(:proofreading_job, :with_start_end_dates, title: "Internal Job", status: 'queued', document: create(:document))}
  let!(:user) { job.proofreader_user }

  it 'queues the WordCountsJob' do
    visit root_path
    click_on "Login"
    fill_in("Email", with: user.email)
    fill_in("Password", with: user.password)
    click_on "Sign In"
    click_on "Jobs"
    page.find(:css, ".clickable-row").click()
    click_on "Upload Proofread Document"
    attach_file('customFile','/Users/mitchellgould/RailsProjects/ProvenWordNew/spec/test_documents/proofread_document/1.docx', make_visible: true)
    find_button('Upload', disabled: false).click
    sleep 2.seconds
    expect(ErrorAccountingJob).to have_been_enqueued
  end
end
```

The js does not fire during the test which causes the test to fail.  This same test was working a few weeks ago and I have not touched the setup. So I have no idea why the javascript will not fire in the tests. This feature works when I try it in the application so there are no problems with the code.

Any help appreciated.

**Update:**

As per the suggestions in the comments I have changed the following:

Updated Capybara to 3.26
Removed chromedriver-helper
Installed webdrivers

Refactored my System helper file as follows:

```
require "capybara-screenshot/rspec"
require 'webdrivers'

RSpec.configure do |config| 
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test 
  end
  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do 
    driven_by :selenium_chrome
  end 
end

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 4

Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
  "screenshot"
end

Capybara::Screenshot.webkit_options = { width: 1586, height: 768 }
```

However, the problem getting the js to fire in the tests persists.  The browser opens the pages load but when it clicks on a button or on an element that is supposed to fire some js nothing happens. The code works as I've done this manually.  I still can't figure out why the js won't fire in the test.

Comment: This is mildly confusing. You're registering the driver :selenium_chrome_headless (uses Selenium driver) and setting Rails system tests to use it. Next, you're configuring `Capybara::Screenshot.webkit_options`, `Capybara::Webkit` and setting `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` which would imply you want to use `capybara-webkit`. You're using a highly out of date version of Capybara, and also specifying to use `chromedriver-helper` which only makes sense if using Selenium (and has been superseded by the `webdrivers` gem).  Which driver are you actually expecting to be used for your tests?

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I guess I'm confused actually and appreciate your help.  I'm glad to simplify this setup if you could just point me in the right direction. I've been looking for a tutorial on this and can't seem to find one.

Comment: Are you expecting to use Selenium with Chrome? If so, remove any line that refers to 'webkit' and then temporarily remove the 'headless' line from the options in your driver registration so you can see the browser open and see what it's doing. Also swap from the 'chromedriver-helper` gem to 'webdrivers'. Once you've done that, run the specific test you're having issues with and see if it opens the browser.

Comment: I've once ran into a typo in an application.js file that caused some time waste, I've figured out what was wrong by logging JS: https://github.com/dbalatero/capybara-chromedriver-logger then fixed the bug.

Comment: Thanks Thomas I will follow your advise and report back the results shortly. I have been using Selenium with Chrome and it works with and without headless. I can see the actions in the browser but no JS is firing. I put an alert to pop up in the code and no alert shows. I will see if the updates change this issue.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will check it out.

Comment: @chell Since the browser is opening - pause the test (add a long sleep, etc) and open the developer console in the browser to see if there are any errors - odds are you'll find an error in one of your JS files is preventing the parsing of the rest (which doesn't happen in dev mode because the assets aren't concatenated).

Comment: I checked and there does not seem to be any errors in the console. However, I think its becoming a problem with the assets pipeline now. The JS was not working in production so I made some changes to fix that. But I'm still not getting the JS to load properly for the tests which I think is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some checking of the JS that was not firing and realized that I had not loaded the JS files after the page was fully loaded with turbolinks.

Putting the code inside the following fixed it:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->

  $('.clickable-row').on 'click', (e) ->
    unless $(e.target).hasClass('btn')
      window.location = $(this).data('href'
```

Updating the capybara was done on the advise in the comments.  While that was not the reason for the issue it was sound advise to keep my gems up to date.